# Safari Not Honoring Display Property for SUMMARY Element

Tags: html, css, safari

`display: grid` is not properly applied to the `summary` element below in Safari.  In modern Edge, Chrome, and Firefox the columns are side-by-side (using CSS grid).  In Safari, the columns are full-width and stack.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: start;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

.card {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

[class*="col"] {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.col-10 {
  grid-column: span 10;
}

details .indicator::after {
   content: '+';
}

details[open] .indicator::after {
   content: '-';
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="grid card">
    <div class="col-10">Click to View More</div>
    <div class="col-2 indicator"></div>
  </summary>
  <div class="contents">
    Here's the amazing contents that are displayed when details are expanded.
  </div>
</details>
```

I've developed the following workaround, but am interested in one that does not require an additional element.

```
<summary class="card">
    <div class="grid"> <!-- <-- I don't want this -->
        <div class="col-10">Click to View More</div>
        <div class="col-2 indicator"></div>
    </div>
</summary>
```

Comment: Known related bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190065 -- I realize it says flex, but probably related.

Comment: Nice find, Jeremy - I posted here because I literally found nothing else about it (and wasn't specifically searching `grid`) - and I see Apple as usual is hustling to solve that bug reported in 2018... ;) - this, combined with some other finds in the recent past have led me to start believing that Safari is the new IE.... :(

Comment: I have heard rumors that Safari will replace Webkit (Google's original engine) with Blink, the latest one by Google that Microsoft Edge also implemented. This can be good for development consistency, but bad for the competitiveness required for technological advances. Although, some call it fake news, so who knows!

Comment: To help with your issue though, the whole purpose of `<summary>` is for semantic markup. I think it is **OK** to use another element for layout.